# redirect htaccess single page with php parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect 1 single page with .htaccess but i can't figure it out

```
examp.co/?language=en
```

should redirect to

```
examp.co/bla/
```

the `index.php` is hidden here because it has already been redirect to root `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^language=en(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /bla/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Thanks, I have experienced same with your answers many times as well :)

Comment: this also redirects every page with ?language=en at the end.

Comment: No, not every page it only redirects: `/?language=en` to `/bla/` See regex `^$` in the rule.